# doing math with dates

Tags: c#, math, date

I am writing a program in c# and I need to do some math with dates. I need to let the user enter a date, calculate the date that is 91 days later, and then find the month right after that. ex: user enters date of 1/15/12, it should add 91 days, 4/15/12, and then return a date of 5/1/12. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this and I couldn't find anything that was helpful.

Comment: You really found nothing helpful at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx?

Comment: So if date+91 lands on the 1st of the month, you still want the 1st of the next month?

Answer (score 4):

```
var oldDate = <your_datetime_variable>.AddDays(91);
var newDate = new DateTime(oldDate.Year, oldDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since constructing a new `DateTime` object has been suggested, here is another approach:

```
DateTime when = <user_supplied_date>;
DateTime future = when.AddDays(91);
when = future.AddDays(-(future.Day - 1)).AddMonths(1);
```

This is a little cryptic, but results in a one-liner that you could use.

Comment: This will give you the month that date+91 lands in. OP wants the 1st day of the month following.

Comment: Fair, was just trying to give some pointers before getting to a proper keyboard.